# RE treat whitespace as one word

Tags: python, regex

New to regex (python). I have a data set that looks like this

`{"Model": "NV3500 HD Cargo"},{"Model": "Armada"},{"Model": "Rogue"}, {"Model": "Frontier Crew Cab"},{"Model": "NV2500 HD Cargo"}, {"Model": "TITAN XD Single Cab"},{"Model": "Altima"},`

I am attempting to only match what model value is IE `NV3500 HD Cargo` or `Frontier Crew Cab`

I am using this expression to match `\b(?!Model\b)\w+`

it matches the correct terms however with models that have spaces it treats them as induvial matches

[image]

How can I treat it as one word

Comment: `"Model": ("[^"]*)"`

Comment: @shawnt00 Thanks for the reply. This seems to match the entire string, i am only looking to match the model value

Comment: Maybe I'm not up on Python regex. Honestly I couldn't even remember if I needed to escape the quotemarks.

Comment: Might be better to decode the data as JSON (or whatever format it is), then work with the resulting data; depending on the situation, that may be more robust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\b(?!Model\b)([\w\s]+)`

Put also it in group.

if you want to capture symboles also, use

```
\b(?!Model\b)([^\"]+)
```